# Has anyone used uwsgi nginx and django for a high-load environment?

Tags: nginx, python, django, uwsgi

I was wondering if anyone has used uwsgi with nginx to serve a high-load django site before. If so, did they have any problems?

Answer (score 1):

We did some tests and it seems that uwsgi just answers with one concurrent request per process. This is because uwsgi DOESN'T fork off another process or thread. If make your application fully asynchronous (you have to use "yield" as often as possible), you could use uwsgi async feature. This should make your app a lot more scalable. As of trunk of uwsgi, threading is now supported with a max number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered performance problems with same combination and successfully switched to [fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/) without investigating much further. Can't recommend but can't give perfect reasoning and analysis either.